# Sprinner doesn't appear in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

This is my first time using the spinner so I was following tutorials.
I was making spinner that will showcase the objects name.

Edit_Form Activity:

```js
class Edit_Form : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mySpinner: Spinner
    private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<Plant_Category>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit__form)
        mySpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner3)

        val customObjects = getCustomObjects()
        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, customObjects)

        mySpinner.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun getCustomObjects(): ArrayList<Plant_Category> {
        val customObjects = ArrayList<Plant_Category>()
        customObjects.apply {
            add(Plant_Category(1, "Strawberry","2 times a day","Water more in summer, Can cause irritation to cats"))
            add(Plant_Category(2, "Aloe","2 times a week","Water more in summer, Is not safe to digest for pets"))
            add(Plant_Category(3, "Money tree", "1-2 times a week","Needs medium to bright indirect light, Safe for pets"))

        }
        return customObjects
    }
}
```

Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.Edit_Form" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/plant_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="101dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="101dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="551dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/edit_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="454dp"
        android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:prompt="@string/edit_type"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/plant_name" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Data Class:

```js
data class Plant_Category(
        var id: Int =0,
        var type:String ="" ,
        var water_time: String ="",
        var details: String = ""){

    override fun toString(): String {
        return type
    }
}
```

The problem is that Spinner shows in the Design mode but it doesn't appear in emulator only the input field appears. I also changed the background color to see perhaps the spinner went to the corner or something but it still doesn't show.

Perhaps there is a problem in measurements in Constraint Layout or how I implement it?

Comment: May be because of your 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit__form)' contains 2 underscore symbols (typo) beetwen words 'edit' and "from"?

What the name has your layout file?

Comment: All of those `layout_margin*` values are highly suspect, on both the `<EditText>` and the `<Spinner>`. Remove those, at least temporarily, and see where just the constraints leave everything.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thank you for noticing it @kirkadev. I'll go correct it immediately and inform you if it's starts working or not.

Comment: @kirkadev The name is correct once I deleted the underscore it's started showing the errors.

Comment: I just checked, everything works for me, but the name of the activity and, accordingly, the name of the layout is standard - MainActivity on live Android 9 device, but spinner doesn't show on Android 5.1 emulator device

Comment: @MikeM. Your suggestion worked the Spinner finally appeared on the screen. The only thing is left to do is move the elements more upwards. If you want the freebie points you can post your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-) Nothin' major. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Just for future reference, you generally don't ever want to use margins to position something within its parent. They're only meant to adjust the (relatively) small gaps between `View`s. Large, hard-coded margin values like that are generally a sign that a layout will only work well for the particular screen size that you're designing it in. Anyhoo, glad you got it working, at least a little. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `layout_margin` on both `<EditText>` and `<Spinner>`. Then the sprinner should appear in Constraint Layout